# how to show specific product for specific city in given time period in-Open cart 2

Tags: php, html, css, opencart2.x

I'm new to `OpenCart 2`. I want to show selected products for selected city in given time period. I'm searching for that but no result as i want.

please help me if anybody know. Thank You.

Comment: If this question had higher quality, it would receive more attention, without needed to add a bounty

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? How is a city even selected? How do you plan to choose which product?

Comment: In stores page many cities  want 3 cities show some products in a given time period not for all cities..

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=18258 this plugin.
I think this will solve your problem